# Compare columns while iterating over rows in Python and increment value

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, increment, python-itertools

I have one dataframe with paired columns (e.g., CS goes with CS_Capacity, RD goes with RD_Capacity, etc.).  I have a column with months, and then a single value that goes with each set of pairs.

I want to compare CS with CS_Capacity in January, and if CS_Capacity is greater than CS, I want to increment CS to make CS = CS_Capacity, and then decrement CSval by the same amount.  Then I want to go to the next month and do the same, until CSval = 0.

Sample Data:

```
data = [['2020-01-31', 3, 6, 7, 11], ['2020-02-29', 13 ,11, 8, 13], ['2020-03-31', 22, 19, 8 ,5], ['2020-04-30', 2, 3, 6, 4], ['2020-05-31', 19, 6, 4, 5], 
        ['2020-06-30', 2, 14, 6, 8], ['2020-07-31', 5, 4, 3, 6], ['2020-08-31', 5, 11, 7, 19], ['2020-09-30',2,1, 4, 5], ['2020-10-31',29, 16, 14, 10], 
        ['2020-11-30',2, 4, 6, 7], ['2020-12-31', 25, 20, 5, 3]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StartDate', 'RD', 'RD_Capacity', 'CS', 'CS_Capacity'], dtype=('<M8[ns]'))
df['CS_Capacity'] = df['CS_Capacity'].astype('int')
df['CS'] = df['CS'].astype('int')
df['RD_Capacity'] = df['RD_Capacity'].astype('int')
df['RD'] = df['RD'].astype('int')

CSval = 40
RDval = 22

pairs = [('CS', 'CS_Capacity', CSval), ('RD', 'RD_Capacity', RDval)]
```

I'm working to loop through the options here to do the incrementing and decrementing:

```
for val1, val2, val3 in pairs:
    df['New Target' + val1] = df[val1] #create new column to store new target- set equal to val1
    df['Value' + val1 + 'Original'] = val3 # starting value incremented row by row
    for index, row in df.iterrows(): # loop through rows
        if (df[val1][index] < df[val2][index]): # for first row, if val1 is less than val2
            delta = df[val2] - df[val1] # create a delta so you know how much to decrement val3
            df['New Target' + val1]= df[val2] # set new target equal to val2
            val3 = val3 - delta # decrement val3
            df['Delta' + val1] = delta
            df['Value' + val1] = val3 # decremented value
        if (df[val1][index] > df[val2][index]): # for first row, if val2 is less than val1
            delta = df[val1] - df[val2] # create a delta so you know how much to increment val3
            df['New Target' + val1]= df[val2] # set new target equal to val2
            val3 = val3 + delta # increment val3                        
            df['Delta' + val1] = delta
            df['Value' + val1] = val3 # incremented value
```

While this code works, I'm having a few issues:

1. df['Value' + val1] does not appropriately increment or decrement.
2. I want to new val3 to carry forward to the next row, so I can track how each row increments or decrements cumulatively.

So, if CSval = 40 to start, and the delta is 3(-) in January, then df['Value' + val1] should equal 37.
Then, df['Value' + val1 + 'Original'] in the next row should start at 37.  Since the next row has a delta of 2(+), then df['Value' + val1] should equal 39.

Current output: [image]

Desired output: [image]

Where am I going wrong?  I want val3 to increment in the if statements, so that should work.  What am I missing?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you please show the output you expect as your code is quite dense and its not totally clear what you are asking

Comment: Added output expectations!

Answer (score 1):

This seems a lot simpler than you are making it. Does this solution do what you want?

```
df['CSval'] = -(df['CS_Capacity'] - df['CS']).cumsum() + CSval
mask = (df['CSval']>=0) & (df['CS_Capacity'] > df['CS'])
df.loc[mask, 'CS'] = df.loc[mask, 'CS_Capacity']
```

At the end of the iteration the value of CSVal is 22 and the dataframe looks like this:

```
0  2020-01-31   3            6  11           11   36.0
1  2020-02-29  13           11  13           13   31.0
2  2020-03-31  22           19   8            5   34.0
3  2020-04-30   2            3   6            4   36.0
4  2020-05-31  19            6   5            5   35.0
5  2020-06-30   2           14   8            8   33.0
6  2020-07-31   5            4   6            6   30.0
7  2020-08-31   5           11  19           19   18.0
8  2020-09-30   2            1   5            5   17.0
9  2020-10-31  29           16  14           10   21.0
10 2020-11-30   2            4   7            7   20.0
11 2020-12-31  25           20   5            3   22.0
```

This solution creates a CSVal even when that value drops below 0, but it only alters the CS value when CSval is above zero. If you want you can clean up the dataframe afterwards by simply doing the following

Comment: Yes, but I need to know the CSval each month, so I can track when it hits zero.  I don't actually need the deltas- just showing so I can QA.  This is a nice simple solution- thank you!  How would you add the CSval column back in?

Comment: Well CSval never reaches 0, but see update. I also see you want to increment CSVal as well

Comment: Yes but this is just dummy data.  In my real data, it does.  Thank you!

Comment: trying it out now

Comment: edited solution as I was overcomplicating it too. This can be done in three little lines of code